# Change an attribute in a mbean using wlst.

Tags: oracle, weblogic, jmx, wlst, osb

I am working with Oracle Service Bus and I want to create a script that will change an attribute in a specific mbean.

I have located the mbean:

```
com.bea:Name=OperationsConfig,
Location=AdminServer,
Type=com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.operations.OperationsConfigMBean
```

and the attribute i want to change is `DomainSLAAlertingEnabled`

Can anybody help me as to how i can change an attribute in this mbean using wlst (weblogic scripting tool)?

How do i navigate to this mbean and then how do i change it?

`DomainSLAAlertingEnabled` is boolean.

Comment: Check the API related to that bean. You will find the solution. If you could tell us what exactly you are tying to do, we will be able to answer it more appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [nice **tutorial**](http://togotutor.com/blog/soa/soa-audit-level-setting-wlst/) showing **howto use WSLT** to configure various Weblogic mbeans.

Essentially, you need to :

1. **Connect** to the admin : e.g. `__connectToAdmin(properties)`
2. **Retrieve the Mbean**: e.g.

   ```
   SOAInfraConfigobj = ObjectName(soaconfigmbean+’:Location=’+locationinfo+’,
                        name=’+appname+’, type=SoaInfraConfig,Application=’+appname)
   ```
3. **Set the desired atribute**:

   `mbs.setAttribute(SOAInfraConfigobj, Attribute(auditlevel,auditlevelvalue))`

Of course, you need to modify the values to your specific MBean and specific attributes.